# How to display price times quantity in minicart

Tags: magento-1.9, price, mini-cart, ce-1.9.2.4

I would like my minicart to reflect price multiplied by quantity per item. Currently it reflects the quantity correctly but the price itself is for a single item, not qty x items. It needs to be the actual price (after any discounts). I also realize this is a large chunk of code due to the conditionals, taxes and other various things Magento uses to show a single price. I'm just not sure what file to reference for this code.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced the shopping-cart code and it appears that I can use this as I don't need to reflect anything but the row total:

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?></span>
```

Worked for me.